# how to transform table structure in to a plain text in a structured manner

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform a simple xml table in to a plain text in a structured manner using XSLT. I am not able to generate the required style. could you please some one to help me on this.

input

```
<table><tgroup>
<thead>
<row><entry colname="col1">head1</entry><entry colname="col2">head2</entry><entry colname="col3">head3</entry></row>
</thead>
<tbody>
<row><entry>entry1</entry><entry>entry2</entry><entry>entry3</entry>            </row>
<row><entry>entry4</entry><entry>entry5</entry><entry>entry6</entry>    </row>
<row><entry>entry7</entry><entry>entry8</entry><entry>entry9</entry>    </row>
</tbody></tgroup></table>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//row">
                <xsl:for-each select="entry">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,':')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
             <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;','')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output

```
head1:entry1
head2:entry2
head3:entry3

head1: entry4
head2:entry5
head3:entry6
```

Regards
Rahul

Comment: You say the input is XML - so please show an example of the input **as XML**. Also post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: You can't expect people to write the code for you, and you can't expect a personal tutorial introduction to the language. You need to ask specific questions: we need to see where you got stuck, and we can help you over one hurdle at a time.

Comment: I absolutely agree your point. My code is not up to the level.
added  my xml and xsl code sample in the question area

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="tgroup/thead/row/entry" />
    <xsl:for-each select="tgroup/tbody/row">
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$cols[$i]"/>
            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```